# Is there a way to make print-color-adjust: exact activate more faster?

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm using the media print to apply my css in the print styles.

But when I use print-color-adjust: exact; to make sure my css works well,
It takes a lot of time to show at the print previewer(When pressing ctrl + P)

the time gap is almost ten time between using print-color-adjust: exact; and using print-color-adjust: economy;

I need that code because of the css.
Is there a way to make print-color-adjust: exact; apply faster?

```
@media print {
    .page {
        width: 210mm;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        page-break-before: always !important;
        print-color-adjust: exact; <- this one makes the print previewer slow but needed
        border: 0;
        background-image: url('/src/lib/images/pdf/background.png');
    }
}
```

Comment: simplify your design? make it more printer friendly?